# Intersection of n lines

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, discrete-geometry

Let $n$ lines in the plane be given such that no two of them are parallel and no three of them have a common point. We want to choose the direction on every line so that the following holds: if we go along any line in its direction and put numbers from 1 to $n-1$ on the intersection points then no two equal numbers appear at the same point. For which numbers $n$ is it possible?

My guess is that, we cannot do it iff when $n$ is even. For the case $n$ is even, I think we should find a point $p$ of intersection of two lines which lies in the middle of two lines (for each of them half of the intersection points in one side of p and the others on the other side of p)

Comment: @hyprfrco I am pretty sure the OP means: follow a line beginning at one 'end', and number the points of intersection in the order that you encounter them.

Comment: @hyprfrco That is indeed less clear ... I took it that the OP suspects that it can be done for any odd $n$ and for no even $n$, no matter how the lines are drawn .... And that the OP is asking for some help in proving or disproving that.  In my answer I show how the Op's suggested proof that it cannot be done for any even $n$ is not going to work ... But that doesn't mean that there does not exist some other proof of course.

Comment: @ hyprfrco, each intersection point lies in exactly on two lines, so to each intersection point is assigned two numbers. The goal is that all the intersection point has two different numbers. but for assigning number you need first choose a direction and then put the numbers along a direction from $1$ to $n-1$.

Answer (score 2):

> My guess is that, we cannot do it iff when n is even.

You could be right! But we'll need a proof ...

> For the case n is even, I think we should find a point p of intersection of two lines which lies in the middle of two lines

No, that won't work as a proof, since it is false. Here is a counterexample:

[image]

The midpoint for line 1 is where it crosses with line 6

The midpoint for line 2 is where it crosses with line 6

The midpoint for line 3 is where it crosses with line 6

The midpoint for line 4 is where it crosses with line 9

The midpoint for line 5 is where it crosses with line 2

The midpoint for line 6 is where it crosses with line 4

The midpoint for line 7 is where it crosses with line 3

The midpoint for line 8 is where it crosses with line 3

The midpoint for line 9 is where it crosses with line 3

The midpoint for line 10 is where it crosses with line 6

Or, as a graph, where an arrow from $i$ to $j$ means that the midpoint of line $i$ is where it crosses with line $j$:

[image]

So: you see that no two lines share the same midpoint!

Comment: I don't understand the downvote ... The OP makes an assertion regarding the even $n$ claim that I demonstrate to be false ... I think that is pretty worthwhile, and without my counterexample, the OP might have spent a good bit of time trying to prove something in a way that I show does not work.

Comment: I haven't checked all points, but your explanation is definitely not a counterexample. Each intersection belongs to two lines and is hence assigned two number (one for each line, depending on the line's orientation). The OP asks when it's possible to choose orientations such that no intersection is assigned a repeated number.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri My example is a counterexample to the claim that for even $n$ there will always be two lines that intersect and that have the same midpoint, i.e. that both assign $\frac{n+1}{2}$ to the intersection point that is the middle point of all their intersections. As I explain in my Answer: there are no two lines whose midpoints intersect.  As far as the claim goes that the even $n$ cannot be solved: that I don;t know, and I didn't aim for this to be a counterexample for that .. it was merely a counterexample to the more specific claim that two midpoints would always intersect.

Comment: @Bram28, thank you very much for your time. yes it's a counterexample for the way I proposed how to prove my claim.

Comment: @MathFun You're welcome!  It looked like a plausible enough assertion about those midpoints (it seems to hold just fine for up to 8) that I tried to prove it for a while myself ... but wasn't able to :)